# Notepad++ regular expression: Search for long strings which could contain newlines

Tags: regex, notepad++, newline, multiline

Given a file containing 100000+ log messages like:

```
2017-08-10T14:49:09: Debug: D-UNK-000-000: [Event Processor] connectorStatus:   Pending
2017-08-10T14:49:09: Debug: D-UNK-000-000: [Event Processor] context:   <DataItem type="System.Availability.StateData" time="2017-08-04T01:10:59.9525690+02:00"><ManagementGroupId>{05120214-5C27-A4EE-D32B-09CB2239421C}</ManagementGroupId><Property Name="Details" VariantType="8">There are 1 messages attached



03.08.2017 21:00:12

Title: Mail sync issue



User Impact: Users are unable to sync emails using Apple Mail on their Mac computers.

</Property></DataItem>
2017-08-10T14:49:09: Debug: D-UNK-000-000: [Event Processor] context_ManagementGroupId: {05120214-5C27-A4EE-D32B-09CB2239421C}
2017-08-10T14:49:09: Debug: D-UNK-000-000: [Event Processor] context:   null
2017-08-10T14:49:09: Debug: D-UNK-000-000: [Event Processor] context_HealthServiceId:   390382B5-C177-0529-DDC0-F2969F667E49
```

Every log message starts on a new line beginning with a timestamp. But some log messages extend over multiple lines; in the example above see the 2nd line containing " context:" and then some arbitrary xml with multiple newlines embedded. Thus, in the example above there are exactly 5 log messages.

*I'm looking for log messages which are very long, say more than 15000 characters.*

I can step through all relevant log messages using Notepad++ searching for this pattern (option "*. matches newline*" selected):

`context:(.+?)2017-0\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:`

But I failed to extend that it will give me only the long ones.

I expected that the following could work, but no luck (it selects the whole file):

`context:(.+?){15000,}2017-0\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:`

---

If this is not possible with Notepad++, I am also willing to use other tools, including command line on a linux box.

---

Not necessary, but if easy doable:
Search for the same what I've explained and replace the whole xml string with its length (number of chars).

Comment: Try `(?s)context:(?:(?!2017-0\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:).){350,}` and adjust `350` to your threshold.

Comment: Wiktor, you are a genius :-) Maybe you can explain how this works?

Comment: I added an answer with a bit of an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
(?s)context:(?:(?!2017-0\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:).){350,}
```

**Explanation**:

- `(?s)` - DOTALL mode ON (same as `.` matches newline enabled)
- `context:` -  a literal substring
- `(?:(?!2017-0\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:).){350,}` - 350 or more occurrences (`{350,}`) of any char (`.`) that does not start a sequence of the `2017-0\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:` subpattern.

The `(?:(?!).)*` is a so called [*greedy tempered token*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970).

Adjust the limiting quantifier minimum threshold as you see fit.

[image]